# Scala/Java template list iteration and concatenation of string

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.5, scala-template

I want to iterate over a list of strings, concatenate them with the suffix/prefix "" and if it's not the last entry of the list append a comma at end.

Wanted Output example: "circle","cube","banana"

My first try is the following snippet:

```
@listStringifier(list: List[String]) = @{
  if (list != null && !list.isEmpty) {
   for ((string, index) <- list.zipWithIndex){if(index != list.size-1){"string",}
   else{"string"}
   }
  }
}
```

But this function is always empty when I use @listStringifier anywhere.

Logging within the @listStringifier block shows that it is iterating, but not assigning anything.

If I call the for loop directly in the template like this following snippet it works:

```
@if (list != null && !list.isEmpty) {
  for ((string, index) <- list.zipWithIndex){if(index != list.size-1){"@string",}
  else{"@string"}
  }
}
```

But I dont want to iterate several times so I want to assign the concatenated string to a variable afterwards.

Any help would be appreciated,
thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `mkString` can do what you want

```
list.mkString( "'" , "','" , "'" )
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning, that was exactly what I'm looking for so I replaced the single quotation mark with the double quotation marks and it worked like a charm. Like this: `list.mkString( "\"" , "\",\"" , "\"" )` Thank you for your help

Comment: Yeah, I put single quotes to not go crazy on the escape sequences (is there a way in Scala to have alternative String delimiters like Perl's `q{","}`?)

Comment: I don't know mate, sorry

Answer (score 1):

mkString can do this elegantly

```
@listStringifier(list: List[String]) = @{ list mkString("", ",", "") }
```

if you want quotes around the strings you could do

```
list.map(str => s""""$str"""").mkString(",")
```

Comment: `(""""""", """" ,"""", """"""")` was requested.

Comment: thanks for mentioning, I tried this before, but that would only append the quotes to the very first and last sign unfortunately.

Comment: @Yeti: You can add the quotes to the separating comma as well to work around that.

Comment: @Thilo as mentioned in your answer it works now, thank you all for your help. I cannot mark both answers as correct, indeed they are from the point of syntax